# Silex, ErrorHandler throws every error level as an exception (how to avoid?)

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm trying to migrate old legacy project to silex. I'm having problem with errorhandler.

In the legacy bootstrap PHP, we had custom errorHandler() that handled all error levels and filtered non fatal errors to mail log / log file. For that to work, we set the error_reporting to E_ALL so that every error would move through the errorHandler().

I don't quite understand how Symfony's ErrorHandler works, Is there a way to filter errors based on error severity? Right now it seems to halt my application on every error. E_NOTICE error for example gets converted to Exception and is thrown to ExceptionHandler which in turn halts application execution and renders pretty HTML exception trace (which I don't really want). I would, however like to set up some error filtering, so that E_*_WARNING would get logged to monolog, E_*_ERROR would throw HTML exception, log it in monolog and send mail notice. How could I achieve that?

**In summary, I need to tell ErrorHandler/ExceptionHandler that it shouldn't halt application execution and throw HTML error, instead it should just log them and continue on.**

Right now I have created my own class "Application" which extends SilexApp. In that class, I set up Providers, Routes and error handlers.
Here is how my errorHandler is registered.

```
private function registerErrorHandlers()
    {
        $exHandler = ExceptionHandler::register();
        $errHandler = ErrorHandler::register();

        //Use PHP closure for the shutdown handler.
        register_shutdown_function(function () {
            if(!is_null($e = error_get_last()))
            {
                $errHandler = new ErrorHandler();
                $errHandler->handleError($e['type'],$e['message'],$e['file'],$e['line']);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You had a look at: [How can I catch errors and exceptions in Symfony2/Silex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089916/how-can-i-catch-errors-and-exceptions-in-symfony2-silex)? Or: [Converting Errors to Exceptions](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/error_handler.html)?

Comment: Yes, I've scrambled through google and looked up all that I could find. These links/articles don't seem to mention anything about error levels though.

Comment: If you want the program to continue then just `return` from your handler after reporting the error. PHP maintains the context of the calling code when a none fatal  exception happens. imo, Think of an error exception as a 'try catch' block and your error handler is in the 'catch' part.

Comment: The error levels are in the 'type' parameter of the error handler. Maybe interesting? [Error Handling in PHP](http://www.sitepoint.com/error-handling-in-php/).  will delete all my connents later.